# Issue improving typing of array type for lib johnny-five

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type the `johnny-five` library which the following .d.ts here is my current pull request, not finished [HERE](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/63773)

I have two classes `Board` and `Boards` which take optionally board ID. ID can be a number or a string, but for simplicity i Accept that it can only be a string

I can instantiate the following way and what i would like to achieve

```
// Simple board
const boards = new Boards(["A", "B"]);
const boards = new Boards()
const boards = new Boards([{id: "A", port: "somePort"}, { port: "someOther"}, {id: "C"}])
```

If ID are provided, then i want to be able to do

```
boards.byID("") // Auto-complete and check type "A"|"B or string or "A"|"C"|string
boards.on("ready", ({A,B,C}) => {
  // allow destructuring on the arg, because i know names which are keys.
}
```

For sake of simplicity, I'm OK to force the user passing an ID: (marking the prop required, whereas it's not on the lib)

```
const board = new Board()
const board = new Board({id: "A", port: "fdsfsd"})

board.id is "A" or string
```

Comment: I don't think you should be changing how you would use the library when you're just adding *types*...

Comment: Sure, but it's already really complicated to write the type :'(